# Specify INSERT columns with query

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to INSERT data from one table to another, where the destination table has all the source columns with a few others in between. The tables have a large number of columns (plus this can get repeated now and then), so I'd rather not explicitly write the column names.

Along the lines of (doesn't work):

```
INSERT INTO dest_table
(SELECT string_agg(column_name, ', ')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  AND table_name   = 'source_table')
SELECT * from source_table
```

The context is that I'm trying to [alter a column's position](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position#Recreate_the_table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering a columns position is going to require a full table rewrite. My suggestion is **not to alter column positions**. However, there is an abundance of people doing this and there are numerous ways to do it. In my experience,

1. one way is far better and easier, **if you have the privileges**, and
2. most DBAs have those privileges.

My suggestion is to use `pg_dump`.

1. Dump with `--column-inserts`

   > Dump data as INSERT commands **with explicit column names (INSERT
   >   INTO table (column, ...) VALUES ...).** This will make restoration
   >   very slow; it is mainly useful for making dumps that can be loaded
   >   into non-PostgreSQL databases. However, since this option generates
   >   a separate command for each row, an error in reloading a row causes
   >   only that row to be lost rather than the entire table contents.
2. Remove from dump what you don't need.
3. Modify table definition or ordering.
4. In a transaction,

   1. Drop the old tables
   2. Execute the script creating the new tables.
   3. Commit